# Изменение свойств у объекта в ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

Если добавить или удалить объект из ObservableCollection, то данная коллекция автоматически уведомляет об этом и изменения визуально отображаются.
Но если взять в данной коллекции какой-либо объект и изменить у него какое-либо свойство, то визуально никаких изменений не происходит.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Вызвав `INotifyPropertyChanged` у свойства, которое может измениться в ходе работы приложения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня как-то в голове не укладывается, как это всё пробросить через коллекцию. Вроде понимаю, что вот есть поля на вьюшке, вот есть для неё ВьюМодель, реализующая INotifyPropertyChanged, вот есть модель. Вроде понятно. Но когда речь идёт о DataGrid и  ВьюМодель, содержащая коллекцию ObservableCollection, то я что-то туплю...

Comment: А что вы там собрались пробрасывать? У вас должна быть коллекция объектов, где каждый объект наследуется от класса с INPC или реализует сам INPC, сам INPC обычно при реализации имеет метод оповещения `OnPropertyChanged();`, его вам просто надо вызвать в необходимом свойстве, например меняется цена товара, было `public int Price {get;set;}`, стало `private int price; public int Price {get => price; set { price = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }`. Все, теперь если вы в коде сделаете `Price = 22`, то оно должно изменить данные в View.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да я видимо на эту тему заморочился https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922130/in-mvvm-model-should-the-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вызывать событие `PropertyChanged`, [оповещать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview#implementing-a-class-for-the-binding-source) интерфейс об изменениях. Удобнее всего это можно сделать посредством реализации интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```csharp
// Реализация INPC интерфейса
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // оповещаем View, если коллекция изменилась на другую
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }
}

// Класс данных
public class MyItem : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _myValue;

    public string MyValue
    {
        get => _myValue;
        set
        {
            _myValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // оповещаем View, что изменилось свойство MyValue
        }
    }
}
```