# Как реализовать привязку коллекции данных к списку значений ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне необходим control с DropDown menu, внутри которого 2 кнопки и список CheckBox.
[image: пример]

Я выбрал Combobox, который легко могу заполнить данными из коллекции, но сделать это в случае с наличием внутри checkbox-ов у меня не получается...

Разметка:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Test Combobox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Text="Types chosen: 0">
    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        ...Кнопки применить и очистить
    </UniformGrid>
    <ListBox BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="Нужно привязать к соответствующему Item"/>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</ComboBox>
```

VM

```
private List<string> items = new() { "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", "Type 6" };

public List<string> Items
{
    get => items;
    set => items = value;
}

private string item;
public string Item
{
    get => item;
    set => item = value;
}
```

Да, можно было бы прописать внутри DataTemplate Необходимое количество CheckBox и к каждому привязать значение. Но в реальной задаче у меня около 90 элементов, поэтому бы хотелось узнать: есть ли возможность передать значения списком, чтобы CheckBox-ы сами сгенерились? Или же для такой задачи придется писать свой контрол?

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}"` Что такое `SelectedItems`? Зачем `ListBox` засовывать как элемент в комбобокс? Что вы хотите вообще добиться? Кобобокс для выбора элементов служит. Если вам нужен мульти-селект, используйте обычный листбокс с мультивыбором. Либо объясните, что вообще происходит, и покажите вьюмодель нормально, а не эти обрубки. Позвонил Ванге, сказала `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>`

Comment: SelectedItems - опечатка, поправил. ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" из VM. Это вся VM - она создана специально чтоб написать нужный контрол. "Зачем ListBox засовывать как элемент в комбобокс?" - возможно это и не требуется. Задача: Разместить внутри DropDown комбобокса, checkbox-ы, которые будут привязаны к коллекции Items, При этом не прописывать внутри комбобокса каждый чекбокс а сделать так чтоб внутри dropdown menu сразу создалась их коллекция. Прошу прощения, не знаю как сформулировать яснее. Допускаю, что задача не решается с использованием combobox - это тоже ответ.

Comment: Что такое дропдаун меню, дропдаун или меню? Это разные механики. Человеческими словами расскажите, что именно хотите сделать и с какой целью.

Comment: Что-то такое может сойдет? https://i.stack.imgur.com/enxaj.png - обычное меню.

Comment: нужен контрол по нажатии на который будет выпадать панелька(не знаю как обозвать, типа как у обычного комбобокса) внутри которой будут 2 кнопки и под ними список (чекбокс + текст). На этой панельке пользователь выбирает нужные элементы (может быть несколько). после чего выпадающая панель закрывается по нажатии кнопки "применить". Выделенные чекбоксы буду потом использовать для фильтрации, уже в рабочей версии приложения.

Comment: "Что-то такое может сойдет? " - Да, такое вполне сойдет! Это обычное menu? Важно, чтобы Items  генерились привязкой к коллекции, а не прописывались на визуалке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Да, такое вполне сойдет! Это обычное menu? Важно, чтобы Items генерились привязкой к коллекции, а не прописывались на визуалке.

Ну давайте попробуем меню

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Select Item" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                    <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Padding="10,5" Content="Click me!" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SelectableItem[] Items { get; } = new SelectableItem[] 
    {
        new SelectableItem("Type 1"),
        new SelectableItem("Type 2"),
        new SelectableItem("Type 3"),
        new SelectableItem("Type 4"),
        new SelectableItem("Type 5", true),
        new SelectableItem("Type 6")
    };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Items.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.Name)), "Выбранные элементы");
    }
}

public class SelectableItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public SelectableItem(string name, bool isSelected = false)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

Выглядит это так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно реализовать управление выбором програмно, то для `SelectableItem` нужно будет реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1132521/373567)).